# Array Manipulation

Tags: magento2, array

Is there any good example of array manipulation in magento 2 using Class `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager` and to use their function in my module like marge array, find any nodes etc.

I just wondering how to use in module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This class is dedicated to handling/manipulating nested associative arrays. More specifically, **heavily nested** associative arrays. It is used primarily when handling data from UiComponents within DataProviders and Modifiers; which, are actually part of a complicated process of parsing XML files as associative arrays!

Most of the methods in the API abstract array traversal by representing them as "paths." (i.e. 'firstKey/secondKey/thirdKey' is equivalent to:

```
[firstKey] => [
    [secondKey] => [
        [thirdKey] => 'someValue'
    ]
]
```

where `'someValue'` is the value associated with the last key in the "path")

Below is a description of each method in the API and an example of how Magento uses them in their core code:

---

### Exists()

Checks if a path exits in a given associative array

Example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php#L607

### Get()

This will retrieve the value of the key (or node) at the end of the path

Example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/ScheduleDesignUpdate.php#L108

### Set()

Sets a value into a node, and returns the modified associative array

Example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Processor/EnvironmentPlaceholder.php#L64

### Replace()

Sets a value into existing nodes and returns the modified array

Example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/General.php#L82

### Move()

Moves a value from one path, to another. If the path doesn't exist, the method provides the option to populate that path with the **$overwrite** parameter

Example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Stdlib/Test/Unit/ArrayManagerTest.php#L207

Unfortunately, I couldn't find an example (outside the unit test) of this method being used in the core code :/

### Merge()

This is an abstraction for the PHP method [array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php). It allows you to do the same thing as the aforementioned SPL method, but staring at specified path

Example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/GiftMessage/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Modifier/GiftMessage.php#L107

### Populate()

Creates an index (or indexes), given a path. It will create an empty array at the end of the path

Example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Stdlib/Test/Unit/ArrayManagerTest.php#L307

Same story as **Move()**, couldn't find this being used anywhere in the code base...

### Remove()

Removes (or "unsets") a particular value based on a given path

Example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/General.php#L301

### findPaths()

Returns an array filled with paths where a specified index exists

Example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php#L113

### findPath()

Gets the first matching path for elements with specified indexes

Example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Downloadable/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/UsedDefault.php#L144

### slicePath()

An abstraction for [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) that allows for retrieval/offsetting of a string sequence representing a path in an associative array

Example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/AdvancedPricing.php#L565

Comment: Thanks for sharing user information but how to change [thirdKey] => 'someValue' to [thirdKey] => 'someValueOtherValue' i try to use marge method but no lucky can u explain how to change values

Comment: Use replace() instead of merge for that scenario.

Comment: On the other hand, merge() should be able to replace keys that exist in the first array and the second array.  I would use replace() if you want to change one value and merge() for changing multiple values.  Can you show a snippit of your code using merge(), and an example of the data you're trying to replace/merge?